# Asterisk Audio Drops During Default Voicemail Intro

Tags: asterisk, audio, gsm

I have a very basic Asterisk install that I'm trying to learn from, and I have a simple voicemail box setup.  I see from the verbose logging that the default voicemail greeting starts to play (and I can hear it in my softphone headset), but the audio randomly drops. I can see by the log that nothing has stalled or crashed on Asterisk's end; it still tries to record my message and registers the hangup event.

It's during this event that I loose all audio:

```
-- <IAX2/1000-1233> Playing 'vm-intro.gsm' (language 'en')
```

I've noticed this has happened on other parts of my system, including `VoicemailMain`. I have tried Googling the problem but haven't come up with much. I'm using the GSM codec for everything, and I'm using the Zoiper Free softphone to connect and test with. I'm also running this on a 256 [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com) Slice with Ubuntu Lucid.

Can anyone give me some direction as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been that I was running this on a 256 slice. I've since moved to RackSpace Cloud Servers and am running an identical setup on a 4GB virtual server and I have no audio issues. Guess Asterisk needs a bit more muscle behind it.